# Why Cast V3 application can not change volume sometimes

Tags: android, google-cast

Reproduce Step :

1. Drag volume seek bar to some position, ex : max
2. Close cast dialog by close button
3. Open cast dialog again
4. the seek bar not set to last position

The same issue has occurred from Youtube / Cast-Sample app.
It seems a timing issue there, how to avoid this problem ?

Thank you.
[image]

Comment: When you change volume, do you see the volume bar on your TV screen changing?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to save position of seekBar in Preferences.

When your dialog opened you have getData(by default you can set it to 0) from Preferences and set it to your seekBar then when you close your dialogFragment you have to save position of your seekBar to your Preference.

Comment: Thank for your reply, but it has another problem, another sender will get  
different value with original device.
I think it should get volume value from receiver.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome cast extension doesn't have volume. Try to connect your cast device to the monitor or TV and the volume will work.